# Qual è la differenza fra 'quindi' e 'dunque'?

Tags: word-usage, difference, conjunctions

Le lingue romanze che conosco hanno più di un modo di dire 'quindi', ma ce n'è sempre uno che è il più utilizzato. Invece in italiano avete due parole che sembrano di connotazione normale - “quindi” e “dunque” - e non riesco a comprendere quando si usa l'una o l'altra. Qualcuno me lo potrebbe spiegare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il seguente estratto da ***[Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_156.html)*** analizza il significato e l'uso delle   congiunzioni "conslusive".  *Quindi e dunque*, di fatto intercambiabili tra loro, sono le  congiunzioni più informali rispetto a *perciò e pertanto:*

> - ***Stiamo parlando di due congiunzioni adoperate nella coordinazione conclusiva.***  La coordinazione conclusiva si ha quando «la proposizione coordinata si presenta come una deduzione logica o anche come una sintesi conclusiva di ciò che è stato detto in precedenza (A quindi B)» (Luca Serianni, Italiano, garzantina, 1997, p. 376).
> - ***Le congiunzioni usate in tale tipo di coordinazione sono quattro, comprese quindi e dunque; le altre due sono perciò e il più formale pertanto.*** Ecco un paio di esempi letterari: «“Veramente la psichiatra prima era molto occupata, quindi credo che abbia visto poco la bambina”» (Dacia Maraini, Buio); «un normalissimo cane nero innocente e buono e al momento abbandonato dalla tua padrona, e dunque tristissimo e bisognoso di una carezza» (Sandro Veronesi, Caos calmo). Quindi, dunque, perciò e pertanto hanno collocazione variabile.
> - Le due congiunzioni derivano dal latino e sono attestate nell’italiano scritto dalle origini della nostra letteratura. Quindi proviene dalla locuzione parlata *(ĕc)cu(m) ĭnde, propriamente ‘ecco di là’; dunque proviene dal latino tardo dŭnc, da dŭm ‘ancora’. ***Si può dire che non esistano significative sfumature di significato tra quindi e dunque***.